# Yarn autorestart failed application

Tags: hadoop-yarn

We've a streaming application running on yarn and we would like to ensure that is up running 24/7.

Is there a way to tell yarn to automatically restart a specific application on failure?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @Aminouvic, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Hadoop Yarn - ResourceManger Restart](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRestart.html)

Yarn will restart the driver if this fails with the feature “yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts”, and by default it’s 2.

Comment: “yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts” applies for all master applications running on the cluster, but we're looking to specify this parameter only for one specific app.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the max attempt of a specific application using ApplicationSubmissionContext::setMaxAppAttempts
[Here is the document for this function](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationSubmissionContext.html#setMaxAppAttempts%28int%29)